# Why does Spring Security's CsrfFilter's CsrfTokenRequestHandler.resolveCsrfTokenValue method always return 'null'?

Tags: spring, security, csrf

I am configuring CSRF protection using Spring Security. However, I am encountering an issue where the resolveCsrfTokenValue method of CsrfFilter always returns null.

In the resolveCsrfTokenValue method, the value is correctly populated, but it becomes null after being returned.

[CsrfTokenRequestHandler.resolveCsrfTokenValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yee1G.png)

[CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVB2U.png)

What could be the problem?

During the debugging process, I observed that the method resolveCsrfTokenValue within the CsrfFilter of Spring Security consistently returns a non-null value. However, when I accessed the value within CsrfFilter, it was always null.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when updating my app to Spring Security 6. I fixed it by using another request handler:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  CsrfTokenRequestHandler handler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
  return http.csrf(c -> c.csrfTokenRequestHandler(handler).build();
}
```

In my environment, `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` is chosen by default and it returns null in the `resolveCsrfTokenValue` method. On the other hand, `CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` just works out of the box.

[Handling the CsrfToken](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-token-request-handler) explains that `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` provides protection for [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH) but does not say additional configurations are required. (I'm still checking why it returns null.)